# How to use BASH variable for AWK filtering results

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, awk, regular-expression

I have this script, I'm getting first letter of my directory name, and I wan't to get directory names that start with the same letter and write to textfile. The for loop is looping list of directory names I have in .txt file.

```
        for dirName in `cat $1 | tr ' ' '_' | awk '/ova/ && !/Nova/' `
        do
                firstLetter=$(echo $dirName | head -c 1)

                mkdir "/opt/SOS/$dirName"
                awk '{ print length(), $0 | "sort -n" }' $1 | cut -f 2- -d ' ' | awk -v var="$firstLetter" '$1 ~ /^ *var/' >> "/opt/SOS/$dirName/seznam-obci-stejne-pismeno.txt"
```

I'm using `Linux version 4.19.0-13-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28)`
Thank you for help

Comment: Ok, I did what I want by grep  `awk '{ print length(), $0 | "sort -n" }' $1 | cut -f 2- -d ' ' | grep "^$firstLetter" >> "/opt/SOS/$dirName/seznam-obci-stejne-pismeno.txt"`, but still I want to know how to do this in awk.

Comment: The question is not clear. Why are you assuming you even need AWK? Are you looking for a solution to your problem or is the idea of showing broken code? You might disagree with the `broken code` part, however, reading the `for dirName in cat ...`  seems like really broken to me.  Please tell us how your file with directory names looks like and what your `End Goal` is.

Comment: You are parsing the same file multiple times. This should be able to be accomplished with a single awk program. Show some sample input data and what the output should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `/.../` awk does not interpolate variables -- it's literal text in there.

Choose one of:

```bsh
awk -v letter="$firstLetter" '$1 ~ "^" letter'
awk -v letter="$firstLetter" 'index($1, letter) == 1'
awk -v letter="$firstLetter" 'substr($1, 1, 1) == letter'
```

Note that, due to the default field separator, a field in awk will never start with spaces.